# How to give Chrome clipboard permissions in cypress 12

Tags: cypress, clipboard

I am testing how "copy to clipboard" works in Cypress using Javascript and I used w3schools website for this.

Here is the code:

```js
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('w3schools', () => {
    
    it.only('using clipboard', () =>{
        cy.visit('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp');

        cy.wrap( //to give permision to read write from clipboard 
            Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
                command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
                params: {
                  permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
                  origin: window.location.origin,
                },
            }),
        );
                  
        cy.get('.tooltip > .w3-button').click()
        
        cy.window().its('navigator.permissions').invoke('readText')        
    }) 
       
  })
```

I tried to give chrome browser clipboard permissions using the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eEc3x24D64&t=210s

However, cypress error message says the permission is still not granted.
[Clipboard permission not granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8mTT.png). Did I miss some additional settings or tweaks? The answers there did not work as cypress.json file is replaced with cypress.config.js

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the latest Cypress version 12.9.0, the `invoke()` command has been changed to a query which changes the way it works. I think this is causing your error.

You can substitute `.then()` instead.

```js
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
  .then((clip) => clip.readText())
  .should('equal', 'Hello World')
```

Also move the CDP to the top - the full structure:

```js
Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
  command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
  params: {
    permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
    origin: window.location.origin,
  },
})

cy.visit('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp')

cy.contains('button', 'Copy text').click()

cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
  .then((clip) => clip.readText())
  .should('equal', 'Hello World')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the code. but it displays a TypeError "clip.readText is not a function"

Comment: It does actually work, check it again :)

Comment: It works well, used it on my chromium-based e2e tests. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use `cy.stub()` or `cy.spy()` to catch the clipboard activity.

Note, there are other ways for the app to interact with the clipboard, so this is limited to the particular page you are testing.

```js
Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
  command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
  params: {
    permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
    origin: window.location.origin,
  },
})

cy.visit('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp', {
  onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    cy.spy(contentWindow.navigator.clipboard, 'writeText').as('writeText')
  }
})
  
cy.contains('button', 'Copy text').click()

cy.get('@writeText')
  .should('have.been.calledWith', 'Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0):

On v12.7.0, you can use the following to grant clipboard permissions.

```
cy.window()
  .its('navigator.clipboard')
  .then((clipboard) =>
    cy
      .stub(clipboard, 'writeText')
      .resolves()
      // @ts-ignore
      .as('writeText'),
  )
```

then you can check the clipboard with

```
cy.get('@writeText')
  .should('have.been.calledOnce')
  .its('firstCall.args.0')
  .should('equal', expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **cypress >= 12.x** versions,

```
const expectectedTxt = 'Hello World!'
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
  .then((clip) => return clip.readText())
  .should('equal', expectectedTxt)
```